# Laravel Redirect to login page after Password reset

Tags: laravel

I need to redirect to login page after resetting password.
Can you guys help me..It's automatically redirecting to '/' url.

Comment: I don't understand.. are you redirecting user to some routes ?  use  route('whatever-your-route-name-is') or use return->redirect('some-url')

Comment: laravel default password reset option working..but it automatically login.I don't need to login..I need to redirect to login page...

Comment: in ResetPasswordController add this line  **protected $redirectTo = '/your_login_url_here';**

Comment: not working....

Comment: Can you upload your code.

Comment: after change it will logged in by self. but you want without login it need to go login page ??

Comment: yes..i don't need to login..

Comment: have you find the way ? laravel 5.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution i got is that,Changing the function in ResetPasswords.php file located at vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/Auth folder.

```
 protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

Comment: if you edit this file, it won't work if you run `composer update` again and don't overwrite their functions in vendor folder that is best way

Comment: you can override `resetPassword()` from `ResetPasswordController` instead of edited it directly to Auth.php

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 5.8** you can do like this -
in your **ResetPasswordController** should be like below it will work

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use laravel auth ,you can find ResetPasswordController here:

```
 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController
```

and simply change:

```
protected $redirectTo
```

to route you want.

if you want to ignore login after reset password,you should edit resetPassword function in ResetPasswords trait that use in ResetPasswordController as below :

```
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    //you should comment below and redirect any route you want like:
    //   return redirect('http://example.com');
    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```